# Livewire Emit function issue

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

Hope you all are doing well. Actually I am new to livewire and I want to Perform a search query. I have two components one is for getting the input data(wire:model) from the input field and second is to get that input data, match it with some entity and display the result but it is not working. I am using emit for it.

```
    <input type="text" name="number" wire:model.defer="number"  class="form-control rounded js-search-by-no"
                        placeholder="Search by No" aria-label="Search by No">
```

```
    public $number;
    public $showForm;
    protected $listeners = ['showList' => 'resetForm'];

    public function searchByNumber()
    {
        $this->emitTo('GlobalSearch.searchByNumber', 'updateSearchByNumber', $this->number);
    }
thats the first component Named as Global Search
```

```
  public $number = '';
    public $numberResults = '';
    public $showForm;
    protected $listeners = [
        'showList' => 'resetForm',
        'updateSearchByNumber'
    ];

    public function updateSearchByNumber($number = '')
    {
        $this->number = $number;
    }
    
    public function render()
    {
        $listNumbers = BookingReimbursement::
        where('amount', 'LIKE', "%" . $this->number . "%")->limit(10)->get();
        return view('livewire.global-search.search-by-number',[
            'listNumbers' => $listNumbers,
        ]);
    }
```

Thats my second component where I want to display result.